# adding an int to a Integer List

Tags: java, integer, int

Inside my `Mappable` List class, I have `a = Integer` list and I want to add `int` inside this list.

Usually `list.add(int)` will work because of java's auto boxing but I am wondering why this doesn't work for me here.

Code explain: During construction of the `MappableList` I can pass in variable number of int parameters and I want to add them all to the Integer list

```
public class MappableList<Integer>{

private final List<Integer> list;    
public MappableList(int... numbers){
  list = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    for(int i : numbers){
      list.add(4);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: You have 9 lines of code and you failed to re-check these lines if they make sense? How does `list.add(4);` make any sense according to your desired behaviour?

Comment: Nice [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (after the edit), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `Integer` as a formal type parameter. If you want your class generic, I suggest `E` or `T` as type parameter; conventionally one-letter names are used:

```
public class MappableList<E> {

    private final List<E> list;

    public MappableList(E... numbers) {

        list = new ArrayList<E>();

        for (E i : numbers) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

If the element type is `Integer` always, you do not need your class to be generic, of course. Just remove the type parameter from the declaration:

```
public class MappableList {
```

Leave everything else (including `<Integer>` after `List` and `ArrayList`) as is (you may correct the number 4 in your loop, though).

Your problem was that with `MappableList<Integer>`, inside you class `Integer` was taken to be the type parameter, not the standard class `java.lang.Integer` that I believe you intended.

Comment: Thank you so much I understand now

Answer (score 2):

IT IS WORKING!!

you are inserting allways the same value **4**

```
for(int i : numbers){
    list.add(4);
}
```

do instead

```
list.add(i);
```

Comment: Sorry I left something out after I add 

            public class MappableList <Integer> 

it doesnt work

Comment: I know you fixed what appears to be a bug in the asker’s code. Still you may want to see [Are “Your code works fine for me” answers acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable) :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
private final List<Integer> list;    
public MappableList(int... numbers){

    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

    for(int i : numbers){
        list.add(i);
    }    
}
```

Now it will work